# LasTools-lasthin-percentile

Tags: lidar, lidar-data

does anyone have any experience with **lasthin** with percentile options?? I have a huge lidar point cloud and I only need 75th percentile and above. I labeled the points which are close to the 75th percentile as class 8 then with using **lasheight** I labeled low noise(class 7) above that percentile. But I am not sure if that is the correct way or not. While applying **lasheight** it asks me to state a height. But I don t know what is the height exactly...

Answer (score 0):

You have to run the **lasground** tool before using **lasheight**. The lasground tool is used to classify the points as "*ground*" or "*non-ground*" for your point cloud. Only then the height of each point can be computed from the TIN generated from the ground points (*class 2*).

Then you can skip directly to the **lasthin** and keep all points above the 75% percentile.